# htaccess directory issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, private, file-get-contents

I'm trying to keep a folder private, but allow an html file to access what's contained in that file.

For example, a .htaccess in the private folder contains
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1

Inside, there is an image named 'hidden.jpg'

Outside the private folder, I want to make an html file with the line
`<img src='private/hidden.jpg'>`

Unfortunately, I cannot see the image. Any ideas on a better way to do this?  I also tried putting the file outside the web directory and grabbing it with file_get_contents(), but this does not grab the entire file correctly (the HTML5 video player breaks when playing .ogv files accessed in this way)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i can't belive file_get_contents() doesn't get all the file content , you can use readfile() instead of file_get_contents() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: readfile over file_get_contents() is not the problem. The issue is that HTML5 video player cannot play a dynamically served video.

Comment: if it's relevant, the ogv files were converted from flv using ffmpeg2theora-0.27

Answer (score 1):

Trying to access a file via an HTML document is the same as accessing it directly. If you can't access it directly, you won't be able to put it in an `<img>` tag, either.

How big is the .ogv file? `file_get_contents()` will fail if the file is too big, because it tries to read the entire file into memory. Try `readfile()`.

But I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Even if you used a simple PHP script to grab a file from outside of the web directory, anyone who knew the path to that PHP script would be able to grab that file just as easily as if it were publicly available. Is it behind some sort of login?

Comment: the .ogv is around 6MB, but I need to allow much bigger .ogv files to be read as well.  And the script is behind a login.  Essentially, those who are logged in can view a certain .ogv, but not other .ogv files.

Comment: Additionally, readfile() displays the hex of the file, wheras file_get_contents displays the video. Do you know why this happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: @user490895 I see, it makes sense if all of this is behind a login. When you use `readfile()` it's a little different from using `file_get_contents()`. Scroll down to the the first example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: ok, i got readfile() to display a video, but that still does not solve the problem.  If a try to play a video using <video src='private/movie.ogv'> it works fine. Unfortunately, I don't know how to protect the private directory. If I use readfile, then the HTML5 player breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little vague, so I'll answer it the best I can.

You have to remember that HTACCESS is *server-sided*. And HTML request (such as an IMG tag) is *client-sided*, meaning it's a completely different HTTP request altogether to get that image tag. Allowing from `127.0.0.1` is allowing the *server* to open it, but not any clients (since the browser, unless on the server, will always be another IP address).

Your HTACCESS code there will only allow the image to be accessed by the server (which is pointless). HTACCESS is to filter/control/edit *HTTP requests*, which are what the browser makes. As it is, your HTACCESS configuration right there won't allow *anyone* to view the image.

What you're trying to accomplish is impossible; the server won't know which request is from which HTML file, and there will *always, always, always* be ways to spoof that request into letting someone access that image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but are you aware of any other way of accomplishing this, such as using session variables as htaccess valid user credentials?

Comment: Personally I would deny from all in HTACCESS and use PHP to serve the content dynamically (since PHP can circumvent HTACCESS restrictions since it uses the files directly). Use fopen/fread with binary-safe reads and use `header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");` (substituting html/jpeg for the proper mime type) and echoing out the contents dynamically, denying access for users you don't want having access to the file (if that makes sense). There are a bunch of guides and code for serving binary data through PHP (just like how it's achieved through BLOBs and MySQL). Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, but the problem with this is that whenever i try to deliver the video dynamically, the HTML5 player breaks. I can see the video, but the scroller is broken.

Comment: That sounds more like a coding issue than a PHP-serving issue. What I would recommend (if you know how to do this, and you have Linux), is to have Apache serve the file and save it, then have your PHP script serve the file and save it, then use `diff` on them to see if there is a difference. (There shouldn't be).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this may help someone. If you add an .htaccess file to the directory and put this inside it:

```
Options -Indexes
```

It will allow you to access the contents of the directory by individual URL, but not view the directory itself.